# Derivation of the K.E. formula without the work-energy theorem (or proof of the work-energy theorem without the kinetic energy formula)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

All of the derivations I have seen for the kinetic energy formula have relied on the fact that work is the change in kinetic energy, something like the one found here: [How to prove equation of kinetic energy (KE = 1/2mv^2)?](https://socratic.org/questions/how-to-prove-equation-of-kinetic-energy-ke-1-2mv-2) .

Also, all the derivations I have seen for the work energy theorem have relied on the kinetic energy formula.

Both of these derivations (at least the ones I have seen), have been pretty much the same derivation: one assumes the work energy theorem and proves the kinetic energy formula while the other assumes the kinetic energy formula and proves the work energy theorem.

It would be great if someone could give me a derivation that doesn’t use math more advanced than basic calculus but anything would be appreciated.

Comment: Kinetic energy is a definition. You can't prove it.

Comment: First starting point for you is to think what energy really is, in Physics and how it is defined.

Comment: First, you need to specify what you mean by "kinetic energy formula". Then you need to specify what definition of kinetic energy you are starting with. Without those two things your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @AaronStevens  So, correct me if I’m wrong, you’re saying kinetic energy is 1/2mv^2 just because we say it is and that the definition is useful. It doesn’t follow from other formulas in physics.

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: I see that the presentation you link gives the appearance of being circular reasoning.  But your question is not clear, so you are getting a lot of negative responses.   Your first sentence is throwing us off.   You don't tell us what you mean by "the kinetic energy formula".   Do you mean $KE = 1/2mv^2$?   If so, then it can't be proved.  It's a definition.  Please carefully express your question.

Comment: @garyp It can be maybe be proven if you start with "The change in the kinetic energy of an object is the net work done on that object", but the OP doesn't want this either.

Comment: Derivations and proofs are essentially the same thing. You could argue the former is not as formal as the latter, but still...

Comment: My understanding after reading these comments is that K.E. is 1/2mv^2 because the work energy theorem says work is the change in K.E.  If I am thinking about this correctly, every derivation of the formula would rely on the work energy theorem. Am I reasoning through this correctly?

Comment: Again, you use the word *derive*.  Look at the last step of David White's answer.  That last step is a *definition*.

Comment: Physics is not math. We don't rely on proofs from axioms for our truth (though we do make extensive use of proofs from axioms to extend small truths into large ones). The "proof" of the validity of the work-energy infrastructure is that it works. Nor is it fully circular. The usual historical treatment is to *define* $\mathrm{d}W = \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{s}$ (note the lack of dependence on energy here), and build up from there. The identification of the kinetic energy of a point mass with $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is just the naming of a term, and similarly with potential energies.

Answer (score 0):

For discrete changes in W and d, under the assumption of constant F, the physics definition of work is:

$$W=Fd$$

From Newton's 2nd Law:

$$F=ma$$

Substitution yields:

$$W=m(ad)$$

Let $d = \Delta x$ and substitute to get:

$$W=m(a\Delta x)$$

There is a kinematic equation that can be used to eliminate the $a\Delta x$ term.  Thus,

$$v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2a\Delta x$$

$$(v_f^2 - v_i^2)/2 = a\Delta x$$

Substitution yields:

$$W=m(v_f^2-v_i^2)/2$$

The right hand side of this equation is seen to be

$$\frac12 mv_f^2 - \frac12 mv_i^2 = \Delta KE$$

Hopefully, this is different than what you have already seen.

Comment: The OP is comfortable with calculus so why limit your answer to  the very special case of constant force and  constant acceleration?

Comment: No particular reason other than the fact that he already stated that he has seen a lot of proofs already, and I posted a proof that he probably hasn't seen already.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified which derivations I had seen before. This one is much like the ones I have seen before.

Comment: I don't know if this answers the OP question, but I think it might.

Comment: @63677, there may not be a derivation that is substantially different than you have already seen.  If you can be a bit more specific (maybe not possible), maybe somebody can answer the question to your liking.

Comment: @63677, I looked at your link.  Do you want to see a derivation for the equation for kinetic energy that does NOT involve the work/kinetic-energy theorem?  If so, are you willing to accept the idea that energy is conserved?